# Force/Suggest the client to use one specific EAP method

Tags: configuration, wpa-supplicant, hostapd, 802.1x, wpa2-eap

I would like to suggest to the client which one EAP method and inner authentication to use.

I'm using hostapd to create the AP.

I've tried by removing some methods in the `hostapd.eap_user` but I simply managed to make those methods don't work anymore in case the client choose one of them.

I've also tried to add a realm, with a specific EAP method, by adding a 'nai_realm' line in `hostapd.conf` but when I launch hostapd it doesn't recognize 'nai_realm'.

Thank you.